# How to perform an OS Reload via Terraform

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We currently use terraform to provision and tear down infrastructure in Softlayer. However we want to reuse monthly hardware for reprovisioning rather than a complete teardown/reprovision. Is this possible using Terraform? Does the Softlayer or IBM Cloud Provider for terraform support OS-reloading?

Thank you!

Reference: https://ibm-cloud.github.io/tf-ibm-docs/v0.12.0/r/compute_vm_instance.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the terraform does not support OS-reloading yet, there is already a issue posted in the terraform GitHub issues. You can see it in the following link:

https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/terraform-provider-ibm/issues/278

You can check the link below may be it help you with your request because it using terraform with rest api calls:

[Terraform REST API calls with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197781/terraform-rest-api-calls-with-curl)